# Convert a list<Strings> into a list<MyClass> using collection’s stream

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, arraylist

Consider this:

```
List<String> users = repo.findAllById(id):
```

And this:

```
Public Users{
int id;
string name;
}
```

The list of users contain a json of users with id and names.
My question is, how do I convert the list of strings(json) into a list of users. Thanks everyone.

Eg. of list:

```
[user1:
  {
    “id”: “24”,
    “name”: “name”
   }
user2:
  {
    “id”: “24”,
    “name”: “name”
   }
]
```

Comment: If you're asking how to parse JSON in Java, there are a millions answers here and elsewhere online. Is there a specific problem or unique requirement you're struggling with?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the value of the String?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want the list to contain strings, and not a User object? If not, you could try this:

```
List<User> users = repo.findAllById(id);
return users;
```

Comment: The problem is that I already have this method name in my repository and jpa repos don’t seem to allow method overloading unless you know of some other ways. Thanks @charbs29

Comment: If you want a list of JSON, there are plenty of answers through stack overflow that can help you convert your models to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how is your `List<String> users` data structure looks like? 
You can do the convert using as below.

```java
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20220924
// JSONObject dependency

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
List<String> strUsers = repo.findAllById(id):

List<User> users = strUsers.stream().map(m => {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(m);
  return new User(obj.getInt("id"), obj.getString("name"));
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you would like to have an accuracy answers 
please provide more detail such

- how you select `sql` ?
- you use `JDBC` or `JPA` ?
- how is the List users data structure?